# How to add a each element of an array into React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to add each element of an array I pull from an API into an existing state in react.
How would I be able to pull out each element and add it to state?

Here is what I know how to do. It doesn't work in this situation because the new data is an array.

state= [{}, {}, {}]

newData= [{}, {}, {}]

`setState([...state, newData])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spread the `newData` so you get a single flat array in the new state.

```
setState([...state, ...newData]);
```

Or

```
setState(state.concat(newData));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a spread operator for every array item. And set state only when the newData has an array value.

```
if ( Array.isArray(newData) ) {
    setState([...state, ...newData]);
}
```

Please let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 1):

In react, Array.map is used to run through an array and get each element.

If the API call is through user input, you can change the state as-

```
  this.setState={i: this.state.i + 1}
```

Assuming your items have  properties-name, location, age etc..
example:

```
   {array.map((item,index)=>{
 return (
      <div  key={index} >
  {index === i && (
     <Component 
        name={item.name}
        location={item.location}
        age={item.age}

       />
     )}
   </div>
   )
  })}
```

If i changes on user input, each object's index in the array will match 'i' and UI will change. The items in each object will be added to the component as a prop.